# How to decoding IFC using Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, ifc

In Ruby, I'm reading an .ifc file to get some information, but I can't decode it. For example, the file content:

```
"'S\X2\00E9\X0\jour/Cuisine'"
```

should be:

```
"'Séjour/Cuisine'"
```

I'm trying to encode it with:

- `puts ifcFileLine.encode("Windows-1252")`
- `puts ifcFileLine.encode("ISO-8859-1")`
- `puts ifcFileLine.encode("ISO-8859-5")`
- `puts ifcFileLine.encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")'`

But nothing gives me what I need.

Comment: ifc encoding is describe here: http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/implementation/get-started/string-encoding

Comment: Where are you getting `ifcFileLine` from? Rails?

Comment: The OP is not using Rails.

Comment: @DenisBolomier according to the docs, every 4 characters between ``\X2\`` and ``\X0\`` represent a unicode codepoint, i.e. `00E9` is [U+00E9](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00e9). You cannot decode this format using Ruby's built-in encoding methods because it is not a standard character encoding but a wrapper for various encodings. Maybe there's a gem.

Comment: 'ifcFileLine' is from my code. Thanks for your answer Stefan !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about IFC, but based solely on the page Denis linked to and your example input, this works:

```
ESCAPE_SEQUENCE_EXPR = /\\X2\\(.*?)\\X0\\/

def decode_ifc(str)
  str.gsub(ESCAPE_SEQUENCE_EXPR) do
    $1.gsub(/..../) { $&.to_i(16).chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }    
  end
end

str = 'S\X2\00E9\X0\jour/Cuisine'
puts "Input:", str
puts "Output:", decode_ifc(str)
```

All this code does is replace every sequence of four characters (`/..../`) between the delimiters, which will each be a Unicode code point in hexadecimal, with the corresponding Unicode character.

Note that this code handles only this specific encoding. A quick glance at the [implementation guide](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/implementation/ifc-implementation/ifc-impl-guide/ifc-impl-guide-summary) shows other encodings, including an `\X4` directive for Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. This ought to get you started, though.

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/776980

Comment: @DenisBolomier Glad to help. If my answer solved your problem (and no one posts a better answer), please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I achieve to acept your answer !

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to implement this in javascript

Answer (score -2):

If someone is interested, I wrote here a Python Code that decode 3 of the IFC encodings :  \X, \X2\ and \S\

```py
    import re
    
    def decodeIfc(txt):
        # In regex "\" is hard to manage in Python... I use this workaround
        txt = txt.replace('\\', 'µµµ')
        txt = re.sub('µµµX2µµµ([0-9A-F]{4,})+µµµX0µµµ', decodeIfcX2, txt)
        txt = re.sub('µµµSµµµ(.)', decodeIfcS, txt)
        txt = re.sub('µµµXµµµ([0-9A-F]{2})', decodeIfcX, txt)
        txt = txt.replace('µµµ','\\')
        return txt
    
    def decodeIfcX2(match):
        # X2 encodes characters with multiple of 4 hexadecimal numbers.
        return ''.join(list(map(lambda x : chr(int(x,16)), re.findall('([0-9A-F]{4})',match.group(1)))))
    
    def decodeIfcS(match):
        return chr(ord(match.group(1))+128)
    
    def decodeIfcX(match):
        # Sometimes, IFC files were made with old Mac... wich use MacRoman encoding.
        num = int(match.group(1), 16)
        if (num <= 127) | (num >= 160):
            return chr(num)
        else:
            return bytes.fromhex(match.group(1)).decode("macroman")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new here, it was my first post on stackoverflow... Why did I get to bad votes ? Is it because the problem was solved ? Is my code not good ? Is it because it's not in Ruby ?
The question was old and I had the same problem, so I thought it could help someone.

Comment: I think both, try not to add answers for the sake of adding them. And a solution in another language cannot always be converted into a solution, especially when there is already an answer.